# Permission errors with os.replace

Tags: python, windows, permissions, operating-system

Permission errors when using the os library to replace a file with a temp file.

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\newewenwekwe_proxies.txt.tmp' -> 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\newewenwekwe_proxies.txt'
```

Code:

```
    os.replace(tempfile, filename)
```

Tried restarting my laptop, closing the file, running pycharm as an admin + running cmd as an admin and running the script. P.S I have administrator perms on my laptop.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66915966/17997115)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `os.rename()` instead.

The reason why can be found [here](/q/69363867).

Answer (score 0):

The `WinError 5` message is unfortunately very generic so there's a ton of different answers out there, and even more unfortunately I think most (such as suggestions to run as administrator), are typically irrelevant. You *should not* need to run as an administrator in order to read, write, or replace a file you own.

So what's going on? There are of course multiple possible causes but a notable one to consider is that the file is already open in another process, and therefore cannot be replaced. Here's a quick demo:

```
PS> python3.8.exe
Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import tempfile
>>> dest=tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix="-dest", delete=False).name
>>> os.replace(tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix="-tmp", delete=False).name, dest)
>>> f = open(dest)
>>> os.replace(tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix="-tmp", delete=False).name, dest)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'tmpuau8nzjn-tmp' -> 'tmpq3lqearn-dest'
```

We hit a `WinError 5` after opening (and leaving open) a handle to the destination file. Unlike Linux which support concurrent writes (the handle continues pointing to the old file) [Windows does not allow this by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5891053/113632).

I *believe* the [`FileShare` enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileshare) could be used by the opener to permit concurrent writes, but I am not sure how to properly use this API with Python.